# Unity3D C# code to teleport

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my player to teleport to a GameObject location When I get 7 points. 
When I pick up my item and my points change to 7 I want my player to teleport to GameObject's location (Cube) Here is the script C#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FpsScoreScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int points;
    public Transform Destination;

    public void Start()
    {

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (points == 7)
        {
        //teleport code here
        }


    }
}
```

How do it get it to work. I want to be teleported to the object that is linked to the "public Transform Destination;" Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its true that your player will not move because of the check you had put in the update() function. Now this is the code that will make your player teleport.

Theory:
The code has a `private bool isTeleported` and a `private function Teleport()`. In the update function we will check if the points are equal to 7 and `isTeleported` is false and then call `Teleport()` function. And there we will set `isTeleported` to true so that the check in the `update()` function becomes false so the player will not teleport.

```
public class FpsScoreScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int points;
        public Transform Destination;
        bool isTeleported = false;

        public void Update()
        {
            if (points == 7 && !isTeleported)
            {
            Teleport();
            }
        }
        void Teleport(){
            isTeleported = true;
            player.transform.position = destination.transform.position;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set your current object's position to `Destination`'s position.

`gameObject.transform.position = Destination.position;`

However if you put this directly in:

```
if (points == 7)
{
    gameObject.transform.position = Destination.position;
}
```

You are going to get teleported to the cube forever since your `points` have not changed and Update is called every frame. You will need to have something to prevent that, like resetting `points` to 0, for example.

Comment: Alternatively you can add a `bool` check and once you're teleported set it to true. (eg. `teleported = true;`) and change your `if` statement to `if (points == 7 && !teleported)`

Comment: It Works! Thanks! There's a little problem. I Cant move my player. That doesn't matter that much but I would like to move my character.

Answer (score 0):

You Might Not Be Able to Move The Player Since Your Player Is Stuck In The Ground. Is That The Case? BTW, Here's The Final Fixed Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FpsScoreScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int points;
    public Transform destination;
    public bool teleported;

    public void Start()
    {

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (points == 7 && !teleported)
        {
          gameObject.transform.position = destination.position;
          teleported = true;
        }

    }
}
```